# Drawable folder for nexus 6 and moto g

Tags: android, resolution, android-drawable

I am using `drawable-xhdpi` folder for `720*1280` devices (moto g) and `drawble-xxxhdpi` for `1440*2560` devices (nexus 6).

But I am facing issue to give support to nexus 6 device, it is also picking the images from drawable-xhdpi folder and images are getting streched.
can anyone please tell me the folders to support these resolutions.

Comment: In `Android Studio` it shows it is `560dpi` so you should try creating a folder named `drawable-560dpi`.

Comment: for nexus 6 or moto g?

Comment: for **Nexus 6** it is

Comment: @Nilesh OP gets notification when a new answer is posted. No need to write a comment for notifying the OP.

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi tried with drawable-560dpi. it is not working..

Comment: We may need a minimum sample code (and drawable resource) to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @hata, sorry i didn't understand what you are saying

Comment: why you need code for this?

Comment: @Saawan Because it doesn't seem a general outcome but a specific one. So, if someone try to examine, it is needed to reproduce. Note that I don't mean your real code is needed. A minimal sample (virtually demonstrate the same outcome as your issue) is sufficient.

Comment: @hata you can try it with creating a imageview and placing the same image in drawable-xhdpi folder and drawable-xxxhdpi folder. then you can see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus 6 has a quantized density of **560 dpi**, which falls in between the **xxhdpi** and **xxxhdpi** primary density buckets.

For the Nexus 6, the platform will scale down **xxxhdpi** assets, but if those aren’t available, then it will scale up **xxhdpi** asset

```
res/
   drawable-mdpi/
      ic_sunny.png
   drawable-hdpi/
      ic_sunny.png
   drawable-xhdpi/   
      ic_sunny.png
   drawable-xxhdpi/  # Fall back to these if xxxhdpi versions aren’t available
      ic_sunny.png 
   drawable-xxxhdpi/ # Higher resolution assets for Nexus 6
      ic_sunny.png
      ic_launcher.png
   mipmap-xxxhdpi/   
      ic_launcher.png  # App icon used on Nexus 6 device launcher
```

see [official android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

Comment: Useful link but this has put me in doubt. As per their official blog post `drawable-xxxhdpi/ # Higher resolution assets for Nexus 6` but OP is already having `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder for Nexus 6. Then **why** ain't they working?

Comment: @nilesh is it possible that the nexus 6 is picking the images from drawable-xhdpi because it is getting the kind of images(high density or dpi or something) that should be in drawable-xxxhdpi folder ispite of the same name of images???

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with `drawable-large-xhdpi` or may be `drawable-large-xxhdpi` for Nexus 6. As its screen size is `5.96”` which comes under category `large` screen size [as per this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: tried with drawable-large-xxhdpi still it is picking images from drawble-xhdpi :(